# I want to add the product from Collection page into Blog page

Tags: shopify

I have one question. How can I import the collection in Blog page?

```
{%- assign collection = collections[section.settings.collection] -%}
{% for product in collection.products limit: product_limit %}
      <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }}">
        {% include 'product-card-grid', grid_image_width: image_size %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I have tried above code, but it doesn't work. I want show the product in 
https://www.luxilash.com/collections/3dminklashes.

Comment: So far what did you try to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you did not set up the configuration for

```
section.settings.collection
```

In the page template. Are you sure `section.settings.collection` has the right value for your case?

For easy approach, please try following code snap instead:

```
{%- assign collection = collections['3dminklashes'] -%}
{% for product in collection.products limit: product_limit %}
      <div class="grid__item {{ grid_item_width }}">
        {% include 'product-card-grid', grid_image_width: image_size %}
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I just grabbed collection code from the URL you provided.

```
https://www.luxilash.com/collections/3dminklashes
```